# What is this type of hat with small pom-poms at the sides called?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

I have seen these types of hats many times:

[image]

They are small hats with ear covers, usually with two pom-poms at the sides and a big one on top (not shown here).

What is the name for these type of hats?

Comment: There's a character in a Jim Jarmusch film who would just call it a 'street' hat.

Comment: Ha ha!  I was going to give you a wee bit of grief over not including your own search but when I Googled "name for hat with ear flaps and pom poms", I got back a preponderance of listings where the hat is literally called "hat with ear flaps and pom poms"! Just too funny!

Comment: I like @Catija's picture of the hat better. ;-) (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The traditional Russian terminology is "[Ushanka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ushanka)", though it is often referred to in English as a "trooper hat".

> An ushanka (Russian: уша́нка; IPA: [ʊˈʂankə], lit. "ear hat"), also called a ushanka-hat (Russian: ша́пка-уша́нка; IPA: [ˈʂapkə ʊˈʂankə]), formovka (формóвка), trooper hat, is a Russian fur cap with ear flaps that can be tied up to the crown of the cap, or fastened at the chin to protect the ears, jaw and lower chin from the cold. The dense fur also offers some protection against blunt impacts to the head.
>
> The word ushanka derives from ushi (у́ши), "ears" in Russian.

Another option is "trapper hats", which seems to describe the same style of hat.

[Here](http://www.loveclothing.com/women-s-brown-faux-fur-trapper-hat-with-pom-poms.html#.Vg6fqXtBDoU)'s an example:

[image: Trapper Hat]

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect there to be a specific name for this type of hat. Nice.

Comment: Perhaps "Chapka" is more commonly used. "Deerstalker" is another possibility, but the word also refers to Sherlock Holmes hat.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't have the pom-poms.

Comment: @Graffito You're more than welcome to submit your own answer...

Comment: @DavidPostill Some do, some don't... it's a broad term. [here's one with them](http://skinnycature.com/shapka-ushanka/)

Comment: The term *ushanka* specifically refers to a hat with ear flaps. A *chapka* has not necessarily the ear flaps. From a linguistic point of view *ushanka* is the good choice, but for many people, both words have the same sense and Ngram shows that *chapka* usage is 25 times higher than *ushanka*.